# TCA error in TYPO3 8.6 while adding new items

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

When I want to add new records in TYPO3 8.6 with go_maps_ext, I get the following error:

```
Argument 3 passed to 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\Localization\DataMapProcessor::synchronizeTranslationItem() 
must be of the type integer, null given, called in 
.../typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/Localization/DataMapProcessor.php on line 195
```

The TCA definition can be watched on GitHub https://github.com/mhirdes/go_maps_ext/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_gomapsext_domain_model_address.php

It dosen't matter if I want to insert a new map or address. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did it work in TYPO3 8.5?

Comment: Yes in TYPO3 8.5 it works

Comment: I am getting same error :(
even though i have changed according to 

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8-dev/Changelog/8.6/Feature-51291-SynchronizedFieldValuesInLocalizedRecords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known a issue, see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79853 in the issue tracker.
the problem is that in the extension the default value for the language is -1 which means "all languages". if this is changed to default, at least that will at least work